# How can I still get higher belt while I no longer attend my dojo

Tags: tang-soo-do

Once I am 18 years years old I will test for my 3rd Dan black belt in Tang Soo Do. After this, I will likely move up to Boston to pursue theoretical physics. However I want to continue martial arts. And I was wondering how I can still increase my belt(4th dan, 5th dan etc.?

Comment: They don't teach it in Boston? Or you don't have time/money?

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options here, both of which involve a discussion with your instructor:

1. Train when home - If you intend on coming home for winter breaks, summer, etc then talk to your instructor about getting drills, form work and other expectations for you to do while at college. Invest in a gopro or similar, send regular videos from various angles of form and other drills.
2. Transfer schools - Discuss your intentions with your instructor, and see if they have any knowledge of instructors local to the school area that would be willing to take you as a student. If they don't have that knowledge, let them know that you would like their support in finding a new school.
3. Hybrid - Find a dojo local to the school area that would let you train there while at school. Talk to *both* instructors and see if they would be ok with you training at both schools.

Your other option is to tell your current instructor "See ya, I'm off to school!", but that's a little rude and insulting to someone that has put in the time to get you to 3rd dan. Also, I don't know how the TSD Federation works, but some systems (Such as ATA) count the person you are training under for lineage purposes when you get to milestone events such as certified instructor, Master rank, etc., so they may still want you under them when you get to that credit.